# Is there a virus scanner for scanning Windows files?

Tags: windows, malware, antivirus

I use Ubuntu as a file server, is there a virus scanner on Ubuntu for scanning Windows files? Since most of the files are saved on the server, this would greatly help minimize the spread of viruses.

Comment: It is not so much viruses but rootkits that are dangerous to Linux. Just be careful with root access, sudo and su commands.

Answer (score 13):

- You can use [**clamav** [image: Install clamav]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/clamav)
- If you want a GUI front end then you should install [**clamtk** [image: Install clamtk]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/clamtk) as well
- More information about antivirus can be found **[here in the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus)**.

Comment: Writing in 2020, this does not really work on Ubuntu 18.04 due to https://askubuntu.com/questions/909273/clamav-error-var-log-clamav-freshclam-log-is-locked-by-another-process, comes down to a bug in Clam if one follows. I was also unable to get Avast Linux to work, seems no longer supported.

Answer (score 5):

Yes of course. Ubuntu comes with ClamAV in the packages:

ClamAV (`sudo apt-get install clamav`) which will install as a service and you can tell it where to check, you can use it joined with sendmail, etc..

If you want to have it in the gui you can also use it there and including with nautilus with nautilus-clamscan (`sudo apt-get install nautilus-clamscan`)

Or look for it in the Software Center or with Synaptic.