# clamav - ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process?

Tags: malware, antivirus, clamav

I have installed `clamav` and I want to to update the files that it uses to identify viruses:

```
$ sudo freshclam

ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

What should I do with this error?

**EDIT:**

```
$ sudo lsof /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log

COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
freshclam 866 clamav    3wW  REG  259,1   100134 10486045 /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

#### Short answer:

You don't have to run it manually because it has been run automatically and is running in the background, that's why you receive that message.

If you want to stop the daemon and run it manually:

```
sudo systemctl stop clamav-freshclam.service
```

run it manually:

```
sudo freshclam
```

---

#### What is happening and how to handle it?

Every time when you encounter into a similar situations, errors like `file x has been locked` or `Another process is using this file : /path/to/x` you can use the `lsof` command to find out which process is using that file, in your case if you run:

```
sudo lsof /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```

You should get an output like:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
abc       126   user   3wW  REG  259,1  100          1048 /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```

The `abc` is the name of process which is using that file, in your case it's: `freshclam`.

That means `freshclam` which you want to run has been already ran by clamav daemons.

you can use `less /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` or similar commands to see what's going on.

So you don't have to run it manually anymore, it's a process to avoid any conflict and having multiple instance of a same process doing same thing at the same time.

If you want to make it stop and run it manually, then send a `SIGTERM` to its process, that gives the process a chance to finish its job and close itself cleanly, something like:

```
sudo pkill -15 -x freshclam
```

- *in this case `sudo` may be necessary.*
- *15: SIGTERM is the default*

Then run it manually:

```
sudo freshclam
```

However in this case you can use:

```
sudo systemctl stop clamav-freshclam.service
```

to stop the daemon.

Comment: Will the daemon start up again after a reboot? If so, do you know the best way to prevent that? Thanks.

Comment: `sudo systemctl disable clamav-freshclam.service` might be the way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out if it pops back up again.

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems to take a damn long time. I've got a good machine and I've been waiting for more than an hour since installation for this update to show any signs of progress.

Comment: just test the status of freshclam with `sudo service clamav-freshclam status`

Answer (score 28):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam stop
sudo freshclam
sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam start
```

Answer (score 15):

This might be another option for this...

```
sudo service clamav-freshclam stop
sudo freshclam
sudo service clamav-freshclam start
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This one helped me!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the most simple answer to the question:

`sudo su clamav freshclam`

Obviously, `freshclam` is already running with the `clamav` user (as `sudo lsof /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` tells us). Call it again in this user's name to wake it up and update the database. Then to check the success...

`sudo less /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log`

Answer (score 0):

Just test the status of freshclam with

```
sudo service clamav-freshclam status
```

If it is running OK (it should show `active, (running)`), you don't have to do anything